# How to make QWidget background with specified png file?

Tags: windows, qt, qwidget

```
MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget* parent, Qt::WindowFlags f)
    : QWidget(parent, Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint)    
    , _pixmap(new QPixmap(myPngFile))
{
    QPalette palette;
    palette.setBrush(this->backgroundRole(), QBrush(*_pixmap));
    this->setPalette(palette);

    setFixedSize(_pixmap->size());
 }
```

myPngFile define the png path. The problem is the transparent part in png file showed black when I show MyDialog, how do I correct it to load myPngFile?

I am using Windows platform with Qt4.8

Please do not use stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really don't want to use style sheets, your problem could be solved by overwriting the paint event of your `MyDialog` class like in the answer of this stackoverflow question:
[Background image not showing on QWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824447/background-image-not-showing-on-qwidget)

But I would also recommend using style sheets for your problem.

Comment: thanks, I repaint it and solve the problem. Just since this is very common request, Qt need to repaint it to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

Take a look at [this:](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/3155)

specifically:

```
QPixmap aPixmap(":/splash.png");
QLabel* aWidget = new QLabel(0, Qt::FramelessWindowHint|Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
aWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
aWidget->setPixmap(aPixmap);
aWidget->show();
```

And [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#transparency-and-double-buffering):

> Creating Translucent Windows Since Qt 4.5, it has been possible to
> create windows with translucent regions on window systems that support
> compositing. To enable this feature in a top-level widget, set its
> Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground attribute with setAttribute() and ensure
> that its background is painted with non-opaque colors in the regions
> you want to be partially transparent.
>
> Platform notes:
> X11: This
> feature relies on the use of an X server that supports ARGB visuals
> and a compositing window manager.
> **Windows: The widget needs to have
> the Qt::FramelessWindowHint window flag set for the translucency to
> work.**

(This bold part you already do, but for future comers better to make it visible)

Comment: I used it, it will make whole widget transparent. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand why you do not want to use [stylesheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) since this it the preferred way. Use the [`setStylesheet`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop) method of `QWidget`

```
setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/images/pixmap.png);");
```

Where `pixmap.png` will be located in the resource file under the `images` prefix. For more details check the [Qt stylesheet examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html).

Comment: coz I need to deep customize the widget.