# Pyside QT Background window translucent not working windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, qt

I developped a program in Python under Linux, everything works, but not in windows.. I'm on W10.

I have a window with Pyside Qt, with on the left a frame with Qpushbutton on a grey background and on the rigth, an png image empty, to get a translucent background. I use this to plot points in this area by visualising other windows on the back.

Here is my code

```
    def initUI(self):

    # Taille Fenêtre
    self.resize(500, 500)

    # Centrage + plein ecran
    size_ecran = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
    size_fenetre = self.geometry()
    self.move((size_ecran.width()-size_fenetre.width())/2, (size_ecran.height()-size_fenetre.height())/2)
    # self.resize(size_ecran.width(), size_ecran.height())

    hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
    vbox1 = QVBoxLayout()
    vbox2 = QVBoxLayout()

    self._frameLeft = QFrame(self)
    self._frameLeft.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)

    # Calcul Courbe
    self._btnCurve = QPushButton(listeNameButton[0])
    self._btnCurve.setIcon(QIcon('ico/curve.png'))
    self._btnCurve.setIconSize(QSize(55,55))
    self._btnCurve.clicked.connect(self.evtCurve)   

    vbox1.addWidget(self._btnCurve)
```

This works on Linux (Ubuntu), not in Windows : the right part is black.
I tried with self.opacityWindow, it works but the whole window is translucent not only the right side. Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

```
    # Transparence
    size_fenetre = self.geometry()
    size_button = self._btnCurve.geometry()

    self._frameLeft.setStyleSheet("background-color:grey;")
    self._frameLeft.setStyleSheet("border: none;")
    self._frameLeft.setGeometry(0,0,size_button.width()+50, size_fenetre.height())

    self._draw = QLabel(self)
    self._drawempty = QPixmap("ico/imgvide.png")
    self._drawempty =self._drawempty.scaled((size_button.width())*1.5,size_fenetre.height())
    self._draw.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")
    self._draw.setPixmap(self._drawempty)
    vbox2.addWidget(self._draw)

    hbox.addLayout(vbox1)
    hbox.addLayout(vbox2)
    self.setLayout(hbox)
    self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

I've just a blackbackground with Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, not translucent. How do manage this ?

Comment: You may need `Qt::FramelessWindowHint`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17805059/4720935

Comment: I've already tried that...  everything get transluscent there is nothing visible even the toolbar.